# Cannot delete detached entity after merge()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem trying to remove an entity, here's my code:

```
  @Transactional
  private <K> void delete(String type, EntityWithId<K> entity) {
    try {
      em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.warn("Unable to delete " + type + " with id " + entity.getId());
    }
  }
```

I don't really understand why, but the remove statement fails, throwing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance
```

The entity manager does not contains the entity, so the merge() is executed every time, and the remove always fails, with different Objects passed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the StackTrace for the caught Exception:

```
Unable to delete log with id 14091612
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance myproj.jpa.AdvertisementLog#14091612
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3DeleteEventListener.performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(EJB3DeleteEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:822)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:880)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.remove(Unknown Source)
    at myproj.batch.impl.DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.delete(DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.java:93)
    at myproj.batch.impl.DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.deleteAll(DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.java:86)
    at myproj.batch.impl.DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.deleteAll(DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.java:80)
    at myproj.batch.impl.DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.deleteAd(DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.java:69)
    at myproj.batch.impl.DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.clean(DeleteOldAdvertisementsImpl.java:54)
    at myproj.batch.main.DeleteOldAdvertisementsMain.main(DeleteOldAdvertisementsMain.java:13)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `remove` is throwing the exception? 
Give us a stack trace. It might be the `merge` throwing the exception, maybe it is seeing the `entity` as detached/removed hence the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: what if you do em.contains() on returned object of em.merge()-- exception indicates entity you trying to remove is not attached

Comment: The Exception is thrown fron the remove() call and after the merge call the entity is still not contained inside the EntityManager... but I don't have any clue fow why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the annotation is on a private method, so its being called from within the class. Is this class a @Service class? Can you provide more details about the method that internally is calling your delete function. Spring Transactional annotations are ignored for private/protected methods. They are only supported for public methods.

**EDIT**

It's not enough to just make the method public, what is the entry point into the bean (from where did you call that private method)? If that entry method isn't called from a spring bean (for instance, from an autowired field) and it isn't annotated with @Transactional, then that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am doing manteinance of an old database and this class is just a batch that recover old entities and deletes them; the class is not annotated itself.
I'll try to wrap the remove() call into a transaction started programmatically and post the results.

Comment: I made the method public to have the annotation working, but still no luck... the error is still the same.

Comment: @DocKuro It's not enough to just make the method public, what is the entry point into the bean (from where did you call that private method)? If that entry method isn't called from a spring bean (for instance, from an autowired field) and it isn't annotated with `@Transactional`, then that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not used to use Spring in batches.
I moved the method in a proper bean, then autowired the bean and called it from my main logic, now everything is deleted just fine.

Comment: @PredragMaric if you make your comment in a response I'll put an answer to that since it's the most specific.

Comment: @DocKuro No problem, this answer was pointing to a solution, I just put in some more details. I'll suggest an edit with these details. Anyway, glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use merge before remove, why are you merging something that you want to delete?

Instead just do like below:

```
//begin transaction
YourEntity entity = entityManager.getReference(The_Class, The_ID);
entityManager.remove(entity);
```

Comment: I modified the code to recover the reference of the entity instead of merging.
This way no Exception is thrown, but no deletion is issued too!
Looking at the log I can see that the only commands issued are select statements...

Comment: Maybe the transaction is not automatically handled and you have to issue the `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()` before the remove and `entityManager.getTransaction().commit()` after it.

Comment: No, removing the @Transactional annotation and wrapping the command in a manual transaction results in another Exception: 'Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead'
Seems like Spring wants to manage the transactions :)

Comment: Try to invoke the entityManager.flush() after the remove. Probably an exception will be displayed.